# Como subir informacion de un Mysql a un EXCEL ya establecido

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

lo que busco es que mi información que presento en un mysql, pueda mostrarse en un excel ya creado, y que solo se autocomplete. estoy usando la libreria PHPExcel
?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora tengo el codigo de esta manera

Answer (score 0):

Utilice esta librería anteriormente, actualmente estas creando un archivo nuevo al realizar

```
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
```

Entonces, debes cargar el archivo ya existente:

```
$directorio = "";
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($directorio);
```

Al final debes decidir si guardas el archivo original, o sí mostras el archivo modificado por pantalla, pero manteniendo el original intacto.

Además tenes la [fuente de SO[EN]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8797103/how-to-open-an-excel-file-with-phpexcel-for-both-reading-and-writing)

Comment: hola juanjoo, estaba viendo el codigo realizado por mark baker en el enlace que comentaste, y estaba introduciendo ese codigo pero resulta que no reconoce donde he guardado el excel(en mi caso excel 2010), donde podria guardar el excel para que pueda reconocerlo?

Comment: Hola, lo mas fácil es ponerlo en el directorio raíz cuando se "complica" manejar el directorio jaja. Sí podes pasar una estructura de como tenes organizado las carpetas te podría ayudar, pero calculo que es un problema de directorio y también podría ser de permisos.

Comment: acabo de modificar el codigo y he añadido la imagen de  como presento el codigo, el consulta.xlsx(que es el excel donde se va mostrar hello y word!) lo tengo en el escritorio, pero no lo reconoce, donde deberia guardarlo y como direccionarlo